# how to remove vertical line from the marerial ui permanent drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I'm trying to remove the vertical line from the permanent drawer of material-UI, any suggestion please.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem, hopefully the Solution is not too late for you.
To remove the Border, simply add `"& .MuiDrawer-paper": { borderWidth: 0 }` as an entry to your `sx` property.

Comment: thank you for your comment, the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
          },
          border:"none"
        }}
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
      >
```

I was working on Mini variant drawer, and I added

```
border:"none"
```

in both `drawerOpen` and `drawerClose`, it works for me.

You can try the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at overriding styles with `withStyles` HOC: https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles
For a complete list of classes you can see: https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/
You want something like this:

```
const StyledDrawer = withStyles(theme => ({
    // css classes overrides goes here
})(props => <Drawer {...props} />);
```

Comment: this is a divider line only in permanent drawer, but I don't know how to remove it (don't know the exact prop of it  ).

Comment: class `paperAnchorDockedLeft` has border-right added to it. Override this class in drawer style. Something like this: <Drawer  paper: clsx({
                        [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
                        [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
                        [classes.paperAnchorDockedLeft]: true
                    }) >

and add style like  paperAnchorDockedLeft: {
        border: 'none'
    }

Answer (score 1):

Target the `PaperProps` to remove the border or for background modifications.
`<Drawer PaperProps={{style: {border: 'none'}}}>...</Drawer>`
`